# Error in a formula field

Tags: controller, formula-field, custom-field

I have a requirement where I need to populate records where a criteria is true.
The criteria is the users must have joined in between Jul,2018 to May,2019. 
I thought I can achieve this using a formula field. Below is the formula:

```
AND((Join_Date__c >= DATE(2018,07,01)),(Join_Date__c <= DATE(2019,04,30)))
```

this would return true if both the conditions satisy.
But when I see in the record, it is displayed as "#Error!" instead of true or false

I do not understand where I have done a mistake. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Do you want to display `true` in the formula field if joining date falls in your criteria, and `false` otherwise. Is it?

Comment: Yes @sfdc_sk...True and false in the sense, check or uncheck

Comment: What datatype are you using for this formula field?

Comment: @rahulgawale return  data type is checkbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this formula.

```
IF( AND( Join_Date__c >= DATE(2018,07,01), Join_Date__c <= DATE(2019,04,30) ), true, false )
```

The mistake in your formula is April doesnt have 31 days

```
DATE(2019,04,31) is not correct
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern over this issue....I tried using your formula. It also returned error as value in the field

Comment: Then probably you will have to check FLS for the field named Join_Date__c

Comment: It is set to visible for all the profiles and being a system admin, atleast, I would have access to all fields. Even in the field accessibility, it is set to editable for system  admin profile

Comment: I have modified the formula in the answer. Try that!

Comment: In your formula, you are using the 31st day of April in the second condition. However April has only 30 days. That was the problem.